# Sock.js Websocket: Upgrade header is missing

Tags: angular

I have an angular 5 app, that is built and served using these commands:

To Build:

```
ng build --prod
```

To Serve:

```
ng serve --env=prod --host 0.0.0.0 --port 8443 --public-host abc.xyz.com
```

In the browser console, I noticed that I am getting this error:

```
         sockjs.js:1683 WebSocket connection to 'wss://abc.xyz.com/sockjs-node/148/n4yhbp1f/
    websocket' 
        failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: 'Upgrade' header is missing 
WebSocketBrowserDriver  @   sockjs.js:1683
```

My understanding is that sock.js runs in development mode and not production mode, because it helps in live reloading. How can I fix it to get rid of this error?